# a value in a radiobutton on tkinter doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I used this program for few weeks and it worked perfectly. Now, without changing anything, it doesn't work. More precisely, the orientation value doesn't change when you click on the radiobutton. Then, the program PosChoisie return 0 instead of either 1 or 2.
I'm on this program for 2 days, but even if I tried hard, I didn't found the error. Thanks for your futur help.

````
    value=StringVar()
    orientation = IntVar()
    radiobutton_Horizontal = Radiobutton(fen, text="Horizontal", variable=orientation, value=1).pack()
    radiobutton_Vertical = Radiobutton(fen, text="Vertical", variable=orientation, value=2).pack()

    def PosChoisies():
        L=[]
        ori=IntVar()
        ori = orientation.get()
        if ori == 1:
            o='horizontal'
            L.append(o)
            #print('horizontal')
        elif ori == 2:
            o='vertical'
            L.append(o)
            #print('vertical')
        print(L)
        print(ori)
        return L

   butValider = Button(fen, text="valider", relief = RAISED, command=lambda:(print(abs,ord,o)).pack() 
   fen.mainloop() ```
````

Comment: _Now, without changing anything, it doesn't work."_ - clearly, something must have changed. You either change the code, or you installed a new version of a library, or something. Code doesn't just sporadically decide to not work.

Comment: why do You have `ori = IntVar()` that is clearly unnecessary, isn't it? also maybe it is used but in the given code `value` is not used as a `StringVar()` so why is that there? Also also in the given code `PosChoisies()` is never called, so could You also show how that happens? and at the end could You just provide a [mre]?

Comment: Also `PosChoisies()` will return either empty list or list of one string, not integer value.

Comment: I tried to add so indications to the code thinking it would help and resolves the problem but it doesn't.

Comment: Here is a code which  call ```PosChoisies()```, but it also doesn't work.                                                                                                                                              ```
def PosChoisies():
    L=[]
    ori = orientation.get()
    if ori == 1:
        o='horizontal'
        L.append(o)
            #print('horizontal')
    elif ori == 2:
        o='vertical'
        L.append(o)
            #print('vertical')
    return L

butValider = Button(fen, text="valider", relief = RAISED, command=lambda:(PosChoisies())).pack()```